# How would I edit MS office document with WebDAV without OPTIONS Method

Tags: tomcat, ms-word, ms-office, readonly, webdav

I implemented own webDAV server by using  Apache Tomcat 8 for edit Word and Excel. It worked fine. But due to some security issues so I had to turn off HTTP OPTIONS Method.
As a result, it can only be used in read-only mode.

Is it possible to turn off HTTP OPTIONS Method but can still edit the document?

Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. The forum for server configuration questions is Server Fault. https://serverfault.com/ Please post your question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, OPTIONS is the way Microsoft Office determines whether a document is a WebDAV document.

Can you explain what security issues you were having with OPTIONS?

Comment: https://www.rapid7.com/db/vulnerabilities/http-options-method-enabled/

Comment: The description of that vulnerability describes the purpose of OPTIONS, I would take it as advice not to serve any sensitive content via OPTIONS, not that you can't use OPTIONS at all. In WebDAV's case, OPTIONS just needs to return a fixed set of headers so you can be sure its safe.